# Using Event Listener in Symfony's console commands

Tags: php, symfony, events

I have used the GeniusesOfSymfony WebsocketBundle to integrate websockets into my system.

I am now trying to push a notification using the following code (this code is located in a symfony command)

```
protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
{
    $messageData = array(
        'message' => $input->getArgument('message'),
        'title' => $input->getOption('title') === null ? $this->title : $input->getOption('title'),
        'timeout' => $input->getOption('timeout') === null ? $this->timeout : $input->getOption('timeout'),
    );

    $pusher = $this->getContainer()->get('gos_web_socket.zmq.pusher');
    $pusher->push($messageData, 'broadcast');

    $output->writeln('Message has been sent');
}
```

This works perfectly. However, how can I check if the `push()` function has actually pushed my message to the scoket server? I want to be able to output "Message has been sent" only if this is actually true.

#### Update

The GeniusesOfSymfony documentation learned me that there are two events to check if it has been a success or an error.

```
gos_web_socket.push_success
gos_web_socket.push_fail
```

But I think i can't just do:

```
if ($event('gos_web_socket.push_success')) {
    $output->writeLn("Message has been sent");
} else {
    $output->writeLn("Message has NOT been sent");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should make yourself familiar with the [event-dispatcher component](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/event_dispatcher/introduction.html) of symfony. The underlying pattern is the [Observer Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern).

To put it short: Events are dispatched from a service (the subject) to enable other services (the observers) to react on them.

This is an example how you may implement this for gos_web_socket.push_success and gos_web_socket.push_fail

First, create your observers (EventListeners):

```
use Gos\Bundle\WebSocketBundle\Event\PushHandlerEvent;
class AcmeListener
{
    // ...

    public function onSuccess(PushHandlerEvent $event)
    {
        // ... do something
    }

    public function onFailure(PushHandlerEvent $event)
    {
        // ... do something
    }
}
```

Register this listeners to the according events in your services.yml:

services:

```
  acme.socket_listeners:
    class:  "AcmeListener"
    tags:
      - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: gos_web_socket.push_success, method: onSuccess }
      - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: gos_web_socket.push_fail, method: onFailure }
```

This should give you a start.

Update:

As event-listeners are nothing more than callables (read: functions), you could implement them directly in your command as well to have access to your $output:

```
protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
{
    $messageData = array(
        'message' => $input->getArgument('message'),
        'title' => $input->getOption('title') === null ? $this->title : $input->getOption('title'),
        'timeout' => $input->getOption('timeout') === null ? $this->timeout : $input->getOption('timeout'),
    );

    $pusher = $this->getContainer()->get('gos_web_socket.zmq.pusher');
    $eventDispatcher = $this->getContainer()->get('event_dispatcher');
    $eventDispatcher->addListener(
        'gos_web_socket.push_success',
        function (PushHandlerEvent $event) use ($output) {
            $output->writeln('Message has been sent');
        }
    );
    $pusher->push($messageData, 'broadcast');


}
```

Comment: I did read an article telling me the same thing. But what is the use of this? I can't exactly call the `$output` from my console command in this EventListener.

Comment: Thanks alot! That looks more like what I'm looking for